# How can I apply a function to a column of a data frame using lapply?

Tags: r

How can I rewrite the `for` loop in the following piece of code using `lapply`?

```
transactions <- read.table(file = file("stdin"), header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for (i in 1:nrow(transactions)) {
  transactions[i,1] <- paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(transactions[i,1], ","))), collapse = ",")
}
```

If you find it easier to work with some input data, use the following as the contents of stdin:

```
a,b
b,c,a
a,b,c
b,a,c
a,b,c,d
a,d,b,c
```

Comment: Why not post the results of dput(transactions) or perhaps only the 1st 10-20 rows. The code you offered will not deliver anything useful. If you want input from the console consider scan (but it will not construct a data.frame.)

Comment: I didn't post the whole script to keep things simple. I'd just like to replace the `for` loop by `lapply` such that I get the same values in `transactions`.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting more code but rather more data. You can see the results of the ambiguity in the data situation reflected in the answers and comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to sort the individual comma-separated components of `transactions[, 1]`.

```
transactions[, 1] <- sapply(lapply(strsplit(transactions[, 1], ","),
                                   sort),
                            paste, collapse=",")
```

Comment: How is your answer different from that of @neilfws? Is using `sapply` just a matter of style or there's a more significant difference here?

Comment: @reprogrammer: have you tried them? Replace `transactions` with something simple like `paste(letters, rev(letters), sep=",")`.

Comment: This answer is wrong because it produces the same output as @neilfws' answer generates.

Comment: Nothing. You obviously didn't do it right the first time, because it doesn't produce the same output as @neilws's answer.

Comment: Hong Ooi: Sorry, your code is correct and has the same behavior as my original `for` loop.

Comment: Hong Ooi: What's the reason for using `sapply`? Is it possible to use `lapply` instead of `sapply`?

Comment: I accepted your answer because it's the shortest and most elegant one. I also gave upvoted you for coming up with the first correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Sample data
n <- 10
d <- data.frame(
  a = unlist( lapply( 
    1:n, 
    function (u) { paste( sample(LETTERS, 5), collapse="," ) } 
  )),
  b = 1:n,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Sort the lists
d[,1] <- unlist(lapply( 
  strsplit(d[,1], ","), # List with the data to process
  function (u) { paste(sort(u), collapse=",") } # Function to apply to each element
))
```

Comment: What is `sample(LETTERS, 5)`?

Comment: To test the code, I needed some sample data: `LETTERS` contains all 26 letters and `sample(LETTERS, 5)` is a vector of 5 letters selected at random (without repetitions).

Comment: I think your answer is close but not exactly what I'm looking for. I'd like to modify a column of an existing data frame that may have more columns. Your code modifies a data frame that has a single column. Could you please change it to modify the first column of the `transactions` data frame as my code does?

Comment: @reprogrammer: I have edited the answer to use a data.frame instead of a vector.

Comment: Your answer seems correct. I need to try it in my own code, though.

Comment: I tried your answer. It's correct. +1 for your correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, you want to replace the values in column 1 of transactions with their new values.

Since you used header = FALSE, I'll assume that the name of column 1 is V1.  In which case, you do not need either a loop or lapply(), since the operation can be vectorized like this:

```
transactions$V1 <- paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(transactions$V1, ","))),
                         collapse = ",")
```

**EDIT:** I have no idea whether the paste/sort/unlist/strsplit works since I can't see the original data. My point is that you don't need loops or apply to transform a data frame column.

**EDIT:** OK, I get what the code is supposed to do now and yes, the above will not work because of the unlist().  But I'm sure there's a vectorized solution...will edit if I find one.

**EDIT:** Right: the best I can come up with is a double sapply(). One to split and sort transactions$V1, another to paste it back together.  It's ugly. Here it is:

```
transactions$V1 <- sapply(sapply(strsplit(transactions$V1, ","), sort), 
                          function(x) paste(x, collapse = ","))
```

Comment: Is the vectorized operation significantly faster than the `for` loop or `lapply` operations?

Comment: I do not think this would work: `paste(..., collapse=",")` concatenates everything and returns a single string, not a vector of strings of the required length.

Comment: Vincent: you may be right, I have no idea whether the function works since I can't see the original data. My point is that you don't need loops or apply to transform a data frame column.

Comment: I tried this answer. As @Vincent Zoonekynd said, this answer is wrong because it concatenates all rows into a single row.

Comment: @neilfws: It really doesn't depend on the input data. My `for` loop doesn't merge the rows of the `transactions` data frame, but your code does. This is how @Vincent Zoonekynd could tell that your code has a different behavior.

Comment: It would help to show us some sample data. I am right in thinking, from your loop, that you want to act on every row, first column?

Comment: @neilfws I added an example input per your request.

Comment: neilfws: By the sample input data that @Vincent Zoonekynd has used is perfectly fine, too.

Comment: OK - I kind of see what you want to do know, but your loop seems to leave the original column unchanged.

Comment: @neilfws: No, `transactions[i,1] <-` modifies the first column.

Comment: @reprogrammer Well, it would if your input data were not already sorted alphabetically :)